# Extracting labels from SPSS files in R

Tags: r, database, label

I imported a SPSS file into R using the haven package. As you can see on the next image, all variables have labels associated with them (e.g. "2016 YEAR OF ADMINISTRATION"):

[image: Labels]

I'm trying to read those labels, however using this line of code returns NULL:

```
attr(X36799_0001_Data[,15], "label")
```

ant this line of code also returns NULL:

```
attributes(X36799_0001_Data)$variable.labels
```

Any info on what I'm doing wrong would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the way you are subsetting, and it should work.

```
attr(X36799_0001_Data[[15]], "label")
```

The explanation of this has to do with the way R subsets. An in depth explanation is here: [Subsetting - Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

You can also use the package `labelled` to deal with SPSS labels. In this case, using the `var_label`.

```
var_label(X36799_0001_Data[, 15])
```

Answer (score 4):

try "labelled" package to get the labels

data_label <- t(as.data.frame(labelled::var_label(data)))

write.csv(data_label, "data_label.csv")

Hope this helps